# Is tilting theory extended also to arbitrary derived categories?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I was reading papers by Rickard ("Morita theory for derived categories") and Keller ("Derived categories and tilting") on tilting theory in derived categories, they seem to focus mostly on module categories (derived categories D(**Mod-**$A$) for some ring or algebra $A$), I was wondering:

Is tilting theory extended also to arbitrary derived categories?

Comment: Yes, instead of defining what tilting objects are, one should define what tilting subcategories are.  Also, it turns out that tilting is a little bit strong condition, one should use "silting" instead.  See, for example, arXiv: 1009.3370

Comment: Thanks, hadn't heard of the term "silting", will give that paper a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Wikipedia links to [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2007-359-02/S0002-9947-06-03909-2/S0002-9947-06-03909-2.pdf) work in the derived category of an arbitrary abelian category (assumably one such that the derived category exists, e.g. Grothendieck,) although it's not a complete generalization as it uses some infinite direct sums.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, I was trying to get a feel for what the paper is about, I also found this http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4785, it's tilting theory applied to arbitrary functor categories.

Comment: Derived categories exist for arbitrary abelian categories, though it is true that Grothendieck abelian categories satisfy a fortiori the assumption of cocompleteness (infinite direct sums).

Comment: @Adeel I mean "exist" in the sense of "hom-classes are sets," i.e. exist without going to a higher universe. If you mean it in the same sense, then you know something I have not been able to find out. The point here of Grothendieck categories is the existence of enough injectives, so that the derived category is equivalent to the homotopy category of the injective model structure, i.e. to a quotient and not just a localization.

Comment: There are more classical descriptions of the derived category than the model categorical ones.  See the thesis of Verdier for example.

Comment: Of course, but by impression has been that something needs to be done to guarantee small him sets.